"collectstatic" takes too long with Cloudinary, works instantly with local storage
I'm having a serious issue with Django's collectstatic command when using Cloudinary for static file storage. The command takes an unreasonable amount of time to complete, but when I switch to local storage, it runs in under a second.
My Setup:

Django Version: 5.0.7
Cloudinary Storage Backend: cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage
Local Storage: Runs instantly
Cloudinary Storage: Takes several minutes (or longer)

My settings.py:
CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
    'CLOUD_NAME': os.environ.get('CLOUD_NAME'),
    'API_KEY': os.environ.get('API_KEY'),
    'API_SECRET': os.environ.get('API_SECRET'),
}

STORAGES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage',
    },
    'staticfiles': {
        'BACKEND': 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage',
    },
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

What I did

Increasing verbosity:
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --verbosity=3

This shows that the process hangs when checking if files exist on Cloudinary.

Using --clear flag:
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --verbosity=3 --clear

Didn't help with the speed.

Temporarily switching to local storage:
This solves the issue, but I need to use Cloudinary in production.

Increasing Cloudinary timeout:
I added a TIMEOUT value to my Cloudinary configuration, but this also didn't resolve the issue.

Using --ignore-existing:
Found out that this option doesn't exist in Django.


My Cloudinary Status:
There was a recent issue with Cloudinary's Aspose Document Conversion Addon, which was marked as resolved. However, the problem persists even after their fix.
Error Log:
Sometimes, the process just hangs indefinitely without throwing any explicit errors.
Question:
Has anyone faced similar issues with Cloudinary? What could be causing the collectstatic command to be so slow? Are there any workarounds or optimizations that can make this process faster?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
